# Insert div tag to top of page with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, append

i have a div tag with position absolute, and top, left = 0. I want to insert before div1 a new div tag id = 'div2', same position absolute, left, top = 0, and i want div2 will push div1 down without changing anything of div1. But i only got two div same position. Please help me.

```
 <div id="div1" style ="width: 100%; height: 30px;display:block;position:absolute;left: 0px; top: 0px;">Content 1</div>

    var div1 = document.getElementById("div1")
    var div2 = document.createElement("div");
    div2.id = "div2";
    div2.style.display = "block";
    div2.style.position = "absolute";
    div2.style.left=0 + "px";           
    div2.style.top=0 + "px";
    document.body.insertBefore(div2,div1);
```

In case i couldn't change any attribute of div1, how could i do that ?

Comment: Then you *can't* have **position:absolute**

Comment: remove the absolute position

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
div1.style.top = 30 + "px";
```

Change 30 to whatever the height is of div2